# Hide UITabBarController?

Tags: iphone

I have root view with both tab bar and navigation bar visible at the beginning. When the view is moved to the next level, I would like to hide the tab bars, and when the view is moved back, I would like the tab bar visible. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a UINavigationController to do the pushing, you can use something along these lines.

```
[newController setHidesBottomBarWhenPushed:YES];
[self.navigationController push...newController animated:YES];
```